# Exclude one regular expression from another regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, is it possible to exclude matches of one regular expression (by writing another regular expression)? For example, I'd like to exclude all matches of the regular expression

`/(cl|g|cr|d)(own)/` (which matches "clown", "gown", "crown", and "down")

from the regular expression

`/(c|g|cl|cr|d)(o(w|u))(n|d)/` (which matches "crown", "clown", "gown", "clod", etc.).

The combined regular expression should match all strings that match the first regular expression, but not the strings that match the second regular expression.

Comment: The following search result gives a few questions that are vaguely related to this one, but I found no exact duplicates: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+exclude+word+from+regex&oq=javascript+exclude+word+from+&gs_l=hp.3.1.33i29i30l4.685.8033.0.9497.45.36.8.1.1.1.342.3792.22j11j2j1.36.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.mazWAc09N-s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmQ&fp=d76eed8efe782f95&biw=1366&bih=639

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could write it like this:

```
/(?:cl|g|cr|d)o(?:un|wd)|co[wu][nd]/
```

But more generally you could use a negative lookahead:

```
/(?!(?:cl|g|cr|d)own)(?:c|g|cl|cr|d)o[wu][nd]/
```

Comment: I notice that this regular expression contains square brackets as well as parentheses (inside the two original regular expressions). Is it possible to write an equivalent regular expression that does not change the syntax of the original regular expressions?

Comment: Also, it would be useful to post a demo of this on jsfiddle.net (so that users can test this function from here).

Comment: `[wu]` is more efficient than `(w|u)`.

Comment: Does this answer apply to all regular expressions, or will it only apply to certain types of regular expressions?